# storing parsed csv using CsvHelper as suitable datatype

Tags: c#, csvhelper

How do I go about storing the parsed csv in a suitable datatype to perform calculations, view it etc. I find a method called records.ToList that seems promisingbut I can't get the syntax right.

```
    class XLOperations
{
    public static void ParseCSV() {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("data.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
            //here I want to store the parsed csv as a List<> or other suitable datatype to work with
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can't get the syntax right"_?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/), `GetRecords<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. So, I guess `csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();` is what you're looking for?

Comment: I just want to do stuff with my record - but I dont understand what data type it is or what to do with it. When I type "records" and add a dot - suggestions like ToList, ToArray pop ups so I figure I need to make a new variable and store it as a List or something. I dont know the syntax for that.

Comment: Then I suggest you do more learning, because it seems that right now you don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: If var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList(); returns a list shouldn't I be able to display an element by MessageBox.Show(records[1]); for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start would be with the CsvHelper [Getting Started](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started) page.

What can be confusing is that `csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();` returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which will [yield](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/12/yield-return-in-c/) records as you iterate over the `IEnumerable` object. What this means is you are not getting a list of items yet, what you are getting is an enumerator which keeps track of where you are in getting records and only returns them as you ask for them.

Often you are getting csv files from disk and this can be a costly operation.  Say you just wanted to get the first 5 records from a file that had 50 million records.  You could call

```cs
var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().Take(5).ToList();
```

This would iterate through the first 5 records on disk and then return a `List<dynamic>` of 5 records.  If you flipped `ToList()` and `Take(5)`, the means of getting the data would be very different.

```cs
var records = csv.GetRecords<dymanic>().ToList().Take(5);
```

This would iterate through *all* 50 million records on disk and bring them into memory. Then it would take the first 5 of those records and return them to you as `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

The difference could be a fraction of a second vs minutes in getting those 5 records and considerably more memory used.

Comment: Thank you! This is probably what creates the confusion. I have read the API but it's very technical and the examples are limited. Probably this library is not for beginners.

Comment: You do have to think about what IEnumerable<T> is doing in the background, but for many applications you can just use `csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList()`.  You just have to recognize that as soon as you call `ToList()` it is reading the whole file into memory.